# What is the fastest and the most convenient way to map SqlDataReader rows to C# classes?

Tags: .net, ado.net, sqldatareader

I am wondering what you consider as the best way to map SqlDataReader rows to corresponding C# classes. SQL-queries are generated dynamically.

Comment: Are you stuck with using `SqlDataReader` or can you migrate over to an ORM solution like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx#)?

Comment: I am particularly interested in the fastest solution.

Comment: Fastest to write, fastest at runtime, what? And some times there are options that are "fast enough but far easier to do", is that acceptable?

Comment: fastest at runtime, that's the point... I am dealing with huge query results...

Answer (score 1):

SqlDataReader is not persistant, it's a firehose, designed for forward-only, read-only access to data. If you want to map SQL queries to classes you may need another approach like strongly typed datasets, LINQ2SQL etc.